# Async tasks in Flask using rabbitmq and Celery

Tags: django, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I created a Django restful API. I send a post request to my Django API which then sends a message to rabbitmq. I have a microservice(Flask) that listens to that queue and processes the information sent by the message broker. I want Flask to be able to process the messages in the queue sent by django asynchronously. I'm trying to use Celery for this but I'm stuck because I see that the task is received but not processed. Below is my code(Sorry for the mess):

````
cel.conf.update(app.config, broker_url='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/', result_backend='rpc://')

@cel.task()
def process_task(data):
    print("Processing task with data:", data)
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Processing task with data:", data)
    return "TASK IS DONE"

@app.route('/persons/')
def hello_world():
    def test_x(ch, method, properties, body):
        decode_data = body.decode('utf-8')
        print("Process start")
        process_task.apply_async(args=('a',))
        print("Done!")
    
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

    connection_parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost')
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(connection_parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='test_micro', durable=True)
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.basic_consume(queue='test_micro', on_message_callback=test_x)

    print('Started test creating Consuming')
    channel.start_consuming()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you are complicating the architecture. You don't have to use flask layer in between if you want to asynchronous process tasks. You can use celery directly with django and both support each other very well. You don't need pika too. Make the same endpoint in django and just queue tasks from there directly.

For processing tasks, you have to start a celery worker in a different process, usually started on CLI through, `celery -A celery_app worker --loglevel INFO`. I guess your tasks aren't getting processed because you didn't start any celery worker.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The thing is for other reasons, I have to put it into this microservice. Also, I think I do start the celery worker because I do run the command you mentioned:

 celery -A celery_app worker --loglevel INFO.